# How to get Order_date last month last day in UNIX

Tags: shell-script, date

We use to run shell scripts through Control-M and shells script accepts execution date as input parameter and script should calculate last month's last day whatever order date we run. I am trying to get the same as below but not able to. Please help.

```
run_date=20210615
startMM_run_date=`date --date="$run_date" '%Y%m01'` --> 20210601
```

Here how to get "2021/05/31" from $startMM_run_date. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming GNU `date`

```bsh
run_date=20210615

# extract the year and month, and set the day as 01, then subtract 1 day
endOfLastMonth=$(date -d "${run_date:0:4}-${run_date:4:2}-01 - 1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d")
```